# Drag&Drop WinForm UserControl object

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, draggable

I'm trying to d&d UserControl that I created.
Here is the UserControl:

[image]

For example, I have two `UserControls` like this in the `FlowLayotPanel`. When I drag one `UserControl` to another I want to merge the `UserControl` data. Merge their labels and images.

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) I don't have the ability to pass the draggable UserControl as an argument to DoDragDrop function.

What I'm doing right now is something like this:

```
        string dataString = "";

        dataString += barcodeLabel.Text + "~";

        string sImg64bit = ImageToBase64(scannedDocImg, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        dataString += sImg64bit;

        DoDragDrop(dataString, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

I'm just passing the data in a string format. I don't think this is good idea?
Is there any other way to pass draggable data? Any thoughts?

Comment: That article says nothing like that.  You can drag anything you want, passing that user control's instance is just fine.  Use e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(YourUserControl)) in your DragEnter event handler.  Do try to make it discoverable, the user will never figure out that D+D can work without a manual.  Even starting the drag is difficult, nothing to click on.

Comment: @HansPassant it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant I realized that the answer was under my nose

Here is what I did:

```
  private void ScannedDocContainer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     DoDragDrop((ScannedDocContainer)sender, DragDropEffects.Copy);    
  }

  private void ScannedDocContainer_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ScannedDocContainer)))
     {
        ScannedDocContainer docContainerDragged = (ScannedDocContainer)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ScannedDocContainer));
        ...
        "Extract the required data here"
        ...
     }
  }
```

This way I get's the entire dragged UserControl

Comment: That doesn't look very correct.  The GetDataPresent() call belongs in the DragEnter event handler, you use it to set the e.Effect property. You don't have to check it again in the DragDrop event handler since your DragEnter handler already checked it.